# How do I find all git revisions of a file which contains foo?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a file `bar.cpp` that I have committed into git.  Sometime in the past, I used to have a `foo` in that file.

**QUESTION**

*How do I find all git revisions of `bar.cpp` which contain that string `foo`?*

**NOTE**

A command-line solution would be great.

Comment: Do you want *all* revisions containing `foo`, or would `git bisect` and `grep` do?

Comment: @minitech if I can start by finding the *latest* or newer revisions which contain `foo`, that would go a long way (btw, I'm not familiar with `git bisect`).

Comment: `git bisect run grep foo bar.cpp` was my idea there, but @StevenPenny's seems better :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use
[the pickaxe](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

```
git log -S foo bar.cpp
```

and if you want the diffs

```
git log -p -S foo bar.cpp
```

More info

```
-S<string>

    Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of 
    <string>. Note that this is different than the string simply 
    appearing in diff output; see the pickaxe entry in gitdiffcore(7)
    for more details.
```